# Multiple syntax error in VHDL file

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I wrote a VHDL code to Build an array multiplier (no booth encoding, no tree structure).  The output multiplier should be able to multiply two unsigned 8-bit numbers.  The multiplier can either multiply signed and unsigned numbers or that can two times multiply unsigned 4 bit numbers.  Also, multiplier can support both signed/unsigned as well as vectorized/non-vectorized.

I am facing multiple syntax errors for using the `for` loops. What could be the reason behind this?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity array_multiplier is
    generic (
        VEC_SIZE : natural := 1
    );
    port (
        a, b : in  signed(7 downto 0);
        cin   : in  std_logic;
        cout  : out std_logic;
        p     : out signed((7*VEC_SIZE) downto 0)
    );
end array_multiplier;

architecture behavioral of array_multiplier is
    signal a_vec, b_vec : signed(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal c_vec : std_logic_vector(VEC_SIZE-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal p_vec : signed((7*VEC_SIZE) downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    -- Generate partial products
    for i in 0 to 7 generate
        a_vec(i) := a;
        b_vec(i) := b;
        p_vec((i*VEC_SIZE) +: VEC_SIZE) := a_vec(i) * b_vec(i);
    end generate;
    -- Use RCA or CSA adders to add partial products
    for i in 0 to VEC_SIZE-1 generate
        c_vec(i) := cin;
    end generate;
    for i in 0 to (7*VEC_SIZE)-1 generate
        p_vec(i) := p_vec(i) + c_vec(i mod VEC_SIZE);
        c_vec(i mod VEC_SIZE) := p_vec(i) + c_vec(i mod VEC_SIZE) / 2;
    end generate;
    -- Multiplex outputs
    if VEC_SIZE = 1 then
        p <= p_vec(7 downto 0);
    else
        p <= p_vec((VEC_SIZE*7) downto (VEC_SIZE*7)-7);
    end if;
    -- Sign extension
    if a(7) = '1' then
        p <= p or (not p_vec((VEC_SIZE*7)-1 downto (VEC_SIZE*7)-8));
    end if;
    -- Output Carry
    cout <= c_vec(VEC_SIZE-1);
end behavioral;
```

Comment: What are the syntax errors you get?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is in the "generate" in the for loop. "generate" is used for the creation of array of component, but you're not defining a component, more on the usual sintax of loop (while of for) on [google sites for example](https://sites.google.com/site/learnvhdl/home/hour-16-loop-and-generate).

Comment: A generate statement represents a block statement which contains concurrent statements A wider category than 'array of component'. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.5 Elaboration of a statement part, 14.5.3 Generate statements for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using variable assignment `:=` to assign to a signal.
2. You are using variable assignment `:=` in a concurrent block (outside of a `process`).
3. Your `generate` blocks don't have `begin`.

Comment: The reserved word begin separates an optional block declarative part in a generate *statement* from  concurrent statements. Without any declarations the reserved word begin isn't needed. Generate statements also require labels. A variable assignment is a sequential statement and may also occur in subprogram bodies. It doesn't seem possible to provide fixes for syntax errors without first identifying them which the OP has not as yet done. There are more errors than addressed here while classic way to identify errors would be to analyze (compile) the VHDL design description.